# How to add new data frame(s) to map using ArcPy?

Tags: mapping, arcpy

I want to add a 2nd data frame to an existing "*.mxd" file. Right now, i see option to add layers and edit properties of "CURRENT" data frame but could not figure out how to add a new one and export outputs from 1st frame to 2nd one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The [limits of arcpy.mapping](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/guidelinesforarcpymapping.htm) are described in the documentation as:

> The arcpy.mapping module was designed so that it can be used to modify
>   existing elements within already existing map documents (.mxd) or
>   layer files (.lyr). In other words, it helps with the automation of
>   existing features but it can't be used to author new objects. It was
>   not designed to be a complete replacement for ArcObjects or an attempt
>   at creating a function, method, or property for every conceivable
>   button, dialog box, menu choice, or context item in the ArcMap
>   interface (that is what ArcObjects provides). You must carefully
>   author a map document or layer file using ArcMap ahead of time with
>   all the appropriate elements and then use arcpy.mapping to manipulate
>   its contents.

Unfortunately, you are trying to author a new DataFrame object which falls outside of what arcpy.mapping is designed to do.